# Dynamic Allocation between c-strings and (ints,doubles,floats)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic

I was making a dynamically allocated array for c-strings. When it get to me resizing my arrays, I would use strcpy,strlen, and strcat to help with the process. This got me thinking that when I make my dynamically allocated array for c-strings, I never have to declare and define a copy constructor and an assignment operator for the c-string arrays. But, if I were to make a dynamically allocated array for a double or float I would have to declare and define a copy constructor to get that deep copy of the array and declare and define an assignment operator to allow someone to make a copy of an instance.

My question is since strlen,strcpy, and strcat  are predefined functions in the C language do they automatically take care of things like deep copies and making copies of instances in dynamic arrays or would it be smarter to define and declare a copy constructor and an assignment operator?

If this is to vague, I can elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has std::vector and std::string for automatically handling such things. You seem to think that a dynamically allocated array of characters automatically gets deep copied, but this is incorrect. The type of your dynamically allocated arrays does not change their copy/assignment behavior; the default copy/assignment provides shallow copies. You would either need to define a copy constructor and assignment operator, or just rely on the more robust features of the STL.

Comment: I apologize I should have mentioned that I made my arrays without using std::vector and std::string. Ok, I understand that the default copy/assignment provide shallow copies and strcpy does not make a deep copy, but it would still be smart even when using these predefined functions to make a copy constructor and an assignment operator, correct?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is since strlen,strcpy, and strcat are predefined
>   functions in the C++ language do they automatically take care of
>   things like deep copies and making copies of instances in dynamic
>   arrays...?

Those are C functions, not C++ functions!  And no, they do not automatically perform deep copies for you.

Comment: You are right, they are C functions, I know better than that. I apologize. I guess I am just having trouble understanding on how I can get away without defining a copy constructor or assignment operator. How is a shallow copy enough?

Comment: C++ doesn't have "deep" and "shallow" copies. It just has copies, which do whatever the relevant copy constructor (and copy assignment operator) says should be done. If you write your copy constructor to perform a deep copy, then all copies of that type will be "deep".